# How to compare value in bidimensional array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I receive the information with this form correctly.

```
$findNIF = User::where('nif','=',$nif)->get();
$findEmail = User::where('email','=',$email)->get();
```

I need to compare if it is the same value the `"nif"` and `"email"` of the `$findNIF` and `$findEmail`.

```
 $findNIF["0"]["nif"];
 $findNIF["0"]["email"];
 $findEmail["0"]["nif"];
 $findEmail["0"]["email"];
```

I use the following sentence but I always receive `"OK"`

```
if ($findNIF["0"]["nif"] && $findNIF["0"]["email"] && $findEmail["0"]["nif"] && $findEmail["0"]["email"]){
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "NO";
}
```

Comment: try to use `isset` or `empty` on array values `isset($findNIF["0"]["nif"])`
Also u can change the query lik so:
`User::where('nif','=',$nif)->where('email','=',$email)->get();`
`$findNIF["0"]["nif"];` try to change to `$findNIF->nif` or if you want to use data as array add after `get()` `->toArray()` and use like `$findNIF["nif"];`

Answer (score 0):

Here

> ```
> if ($findNIF["0"]["nif"] && $findNIF["0"]["email"] && $findEmail["0"]["nif"] && $findEmail["0"]["email"]){
>     echo "OK";
> } else {
>     echo "NO";
> }
> ```

in your condition if you get values in both of your `$findNIF` and `$findEmail` variables then it always return true.

If you want to compare the `nif` of `$findNIF` & `$findEmail` and `email` of `$findNIF` & `$findEmail` both then this would be like this

```
if (($findNIF["0"]["nif"] == $findEmail["0"]["nif"]) && ($findNIF["0"]["email"] == $findEmail["0"]["email"])){
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "NO";
}
```

Please elaborate more about what you need.